# CUDA Lookup Table vs. Algorithm

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, lookup-tables

I know this can be tested but I am interested in the theory, on paper what should be faster.

I'm trying to work out what would be theoretically faster, a random look-up from a table in shared memory (so bank conflicts possible) vs an algorithm with say, 'n' fp multiplications.

Best case scenario is the shared memory look-up has no bank conflicts and so takes 20-40 clock cycles, worst case is 32 bank conflicts and 640-1280 clock cycles. The multiplications will be 'n' * cycles per instruction. Is this proper reasoning?

Do the fp multiplications each take 1 cycle? 5 cycles? At which point, as a number of multiplications, does it make sense to use a shared memory look-up table?

Comment: Having looked into this situation multiple times in various contexts, I would strongly suggest the experimental approach. Given the complexities of program execution on GPUs, I don't think the trade-offs can be theoretically modeled with sufficient accuracy based on publicly available information. On GPUs, on-the-fly computation frequently beats lookup tables in terms of performance.

Comment: Agreeing with njuffra on the experimental approach. This strongly depend on the size of your data. There is also a cache which is very efficient if your data is read-only: the constant cache. If your look-up table fits in there you also want to try it as it does not have same rules as shared memory (including allocation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The multiplications will be 'n' x cycles per instruction. Is this proper reasoning?*  When doing 'n' fp multiplications, it is keeping the cores busy with those operations. It's probably not just 'mult' instructions, it will be other ones like 'mov' in-between also. So maybe it might be n*3 instructions total.  When you fetch a cached value from shared memory the (20-40) * 5(avg max bank conflicts..guessing)= ~150 clocks the cores are free to do other things. If the kernel is compute bound(limited) then using shared memory might be more efficient. If the kernel has limited shared memory or using more shared memory would result in fewer in-flight warps then re-calculating it would be faster.

*Do the fp multiplications each take 1 cycle? 5 cycles?* 
When I wrote [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/409477/ptx-assembly-instruction-timing-project-comments-and-questions-trying-to-calculate-instruction-tim/) it was 6 cycles but that was 7 years ago. It might (or might not) be faster now.  This is only for a particular core though and not the entire SM.

*At which point, as a number of multiplications, does it make sense to use a shared memory look-up table?*  It's really hard to say. There are a lot of variables here like GPU generation, what the rest of the kernel is doing, the setup time for the shared memory, etc.

A problem with building random numbers in a kernel is also the additional registers requirements. This might cause slowdown for the rest of the kernel because there would be more register usage so that could cause less occupancy.

Another solution (again depending on the problem) would be to use a GPU RNG and fill a global memory array with random numbers. Then have your kernel access these. It would take 300-500 clock cycles but there would not be any bank conflicts.  Also with Pascal(not release yet) there will be hbm2 and this will likely lower the global memory access time even further.

Hope this helps.  Hopefully some other experts can chime in and give you better information.